# Alternative for #subList() for String array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

So I modified an API (for command management) to use String[] instead of a list of Strings.

My problem is here:`strings.subList(1, strings.length)`
So I need to change this to a different alternative that would do the same job.

What exactly could I do here?

Comment: I can't read that code. Could you please reformat it?

Comment: (The proposed duplicate wasn't a duplicate, IMO - this is explicitly looking for an equivalent of subList, which provides a *view* of part of an list.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Perhaps I'm just misinterpreting the question; to me it sounds like the OP wants to rewrite his code from Lists to arrays, but can't figure out an equivalent to subList.  (But agree that copyOfRange, etc. won't provide a view...)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Yes, but at least the *answers* to the question you marked as a duplicate were all not equivalent to subList, as they were creating copies. I agree the questions sound similar, but with the explicit use of `subList` in this question, I think they're different enough to both stand separately.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get one array which is a sliced view of another - but you *can* make a list view over an array, and then use sublist on that:

```
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(strings);
List<String> subList = stringList.subList(1, strings.length);
```

Now you won't be able to pass that to anything taking an array, of course...

So your options are:

- Go back to using a `List<String>` everywhere - this would be my suggestion, as collection classes are generally more flexible than arrays
- Use arrays for part of the code, but collection classes elsewhere
- Copy part of the array instead (e.g. using `System.arraycopy` or `Arrays.copyOfRange`)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to copy just part of an array into a new array, I would advise that you use the [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-T:A-int-int-) function:

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(strings, 1, strings.length());
```

(sees Jon Skeet's answer, skitters away sheepishly)